# Can Parse be used in place of my MySQL database? (after converted to NoSQL)

Tags: mysql

Can I dump my sql database, and upload each table to Parse so that it can serve as a multi-table (whatever the NoSql terminology is) database for my project?

Answer (score 0):

Parse can be used with PHP, JS, and many other languages of the web, so in theory, yes. It also has an import feature so you can import data. I'm not sure how well this feature works, but it is definitely worth a try. [Here is the documentation.](https://parse.com/docs/php_guide)

Comment: Does Parse have a method for "joining" two or more of these "tables", similar to SQL?